# WordPress : How to use IF statement with redux?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, redux-framework

I have installed the redux option framework into my theme and made it work so things change when I add the sample `config` file. (and when I do `print_r($redux_demo);` in `functions.php` I get a wall of text at the top)

Problem I have is that I want to make it work in my theme. So I bought two other theme that use redux (seashell by meks and total by WPExplorer) to get some knowledge how to implement it but I just don't get it :(

I'm newbie to php and I wonder of you guys could explain how to do this with redux?

```
<?php if (something): ?>
<h1>It Works!!!</h1> <?php endif; ?>
```

I see that Seashell template do something like this:

```
<?php if($favicon = shl_get_option('favicon')): ?>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $favicon;?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

So I want to just link the if statement to the "demo switch" (ID: switch-on) and make it work.

```
<?php if ($redux_demo('switch-on')): ?>
        <h1>It Works!!!</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How do you do this? :)

Answer (score 1):

Just saw this question, I'm surprised it had no answer.

```
<?php if (true == $redux_demo('switch-on')): ?>
    <h1>It Works!!!</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

(note the [use of Yoda conditions](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/#yoda-conditions) as well, which avoids accidentally introducing a tricky bug if you mistype an == as =)

Comment: you need to use brackets, not parenthesis. $redux_demo('switch-on') change it with $redux_demo['switch-on']